# BHO memory leak

Tags: c#, mshtml, bho

I've written a BHO based on this tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Attach_BHO_with_C_.aspx

My `GetSite` and `SetSite` are identical to the tutorials listing. I am adding/removing an `OnDocumentComplete` handler and assigning `SHDocVW.WebBrowser webBrowser` inside the `IObjectWithSite` SetSite function

for debugging purposes I've removed all but basic functionality. Here is my `OnDocumentComplete` handler.

```
    public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        if (true)
        {

            HTMLDocument document;
            document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
            /*need to do some stuff here to the doc*/
            //then free up script references somehow?
        }
        return;
    }
```

When I attach my VS2008 debugger to an IE instance, I notice all loaded .js are sticking around after their respective windows/tabs are closed. If I set the conditional in OnDocumentComplete to false (or disable my BHO) the leak goes away. Is there more cleanup I need to do on the mshtml.HTMLDocument? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to close the document at all? Isn't it the same document that you want to display in the browser? By the way, setting a local variable to null makes no difference here.

Comment: I suppose I don't. I am assuming there is a reference hanging out to these .js files and thats why they are not falling off when the page is closed. You're right, there is no change if I do not call document.close() or set document to null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [calling `Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(document)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx).